# Passing multiple values as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How can I pass query to Story component

```
   function Story({data}) {
       return (<div></div>)
   }

   function Feedbacks({feedbackdata}) {
        const {query, feedbacks} = feedbackdata;
      
        return (
            <div>
                {feedbacks.length > 0 && feedbacks.map(feedback => <Story key={feedbacks.id} data={feedback}/>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You add a prop to `Story`.

```
function Story({data, query}) {
  return (<div></div>)
}
```

Then pass in that prop like:

```
<Story key={feedbacks.id} data={feedback} query={query} />
```

[See the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) for more info about props. You can add as many as you like!

Answer (score 0):

Just add it as prop?

and make sure that your `Story` function/class component handles that extra prop

```
   function Story({data}) {
       return (<div></div>)
   }

   function Feedbacks({feedbackdata}) {
        const {query, feedbacks} = feedbackdata;
      
        return (
            <div>
                {feedbacks.length > 0 && feedbacks.map(feedback => <Story key={feedbacks.id} data={feedback} query={query} />)}
            </div>
        )
    }
```